# Assigning a tuple to a variable while html5 scraping

Tags: python

I have a set of tickers that I want to search up options contracts for. I am able to run the following code individually for each ticker, however, I wanted to inquire if there was some sort of iterative process where I could look up all tickers using the least amount of code.

here is the code:

```
stock = 'AAPL'

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

chain = options.get_options_chain(stock, 'October 15, 2021')

print(chain['calls'])
```

I've tried to change the variable "stock" into `stock = 'AAPL','AMZN'` to look up more stocks at once, however, this method returns the following error:

`"TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str"`

I am new to coding, and any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: you need to learn to use lists and for loops.

Answer (score 0):

You have tuple not string if you want to concatentate a tuple with string you can first create a string with tuple and do the concatenation as shown below. In your case you have to create string for stock tuple.

```
stock_string = ','.join(stock)
print (stock_string+"Concatenated String")
```

Here you are first creating a string from tuples by joining with ",". Now You can do the concatenation with another string.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the API, but it looks like you are defining stock as a tuple.
I suspect you need to do something like

```
for stock in mystocks:
    chain = options.get_options_chain(stock, 'October 15, 2021')
    # do something with chain
    enter code here
```

or,

```
chains = [ options.get_options_chain(stock, 'October 15, 2021') for stock in mystocks ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked!!!